# Oracle still showing spool statement despite "set serveroutput off"?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, hint, spool

I'm running the following commands:

```
SET PAGESIZE 1000 LINESIZE 500 ECHO OFF TRIMS ON TAB OFF FEEDBACK OFF HEADING OFF SERVEROUTPUT OFF

SPOOL c:/filea1.sql
SELECT /*INSERT*/ * FROM TBL WHERE A = 1;

SPOOL c:/filea2.sql
SELECT /*INSERT*/ * FROM TBL WHERE A = 2;

SPOOL c:/filea3.sql
SELECT /*INSERT*/ * FROM TBL WHERE A = 3;
```

Every file except the last one has the spool statement at the last line of the file like so -

```
row1
row2     
SQL> spool C:\next_file_name.sql
```

I tried putting the set statement between each pair spool and select statement but the result is the same. I also tried breaking the set line into individual statements and putting them all between the spool/select but the result is still the same.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `set serveroutput` only controls `dbms_output`. It's not related to any other SQL\*Plus output settings.

Comment: Setting server output to off works when I run the same thing but with only one file. Isn't the "SQL> spool " line dbms_output?

Comment: No. `dbms_output` is a package with a `put_line` procedure (amongst other things), which places the specified text into an array which the client application can fetch and display when the database call completes. `set serveroutput` controls whether you want SQL\*Plus to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to put code you posted:

```
set pagesize ...

...

SELECT /*INSERT*/ * FROM TBL WHERE A = 3;
```

into a .sql script (let's call it `moshe.sql`). Then, at SQL*Plus prompt, run that script:

```
SQL> moshe.sql
```

It'll make the result look as you expected.

BTW, don't forget to `spool off` once you're done (you "forgot" to do that in your code).

Comment: Ok I'm trying to run sqlplus from the command line (on windows), getting ORA-12560 TNS: Protocol Adapter Error. Did some googling but not sure what do with that. Will post another question, hopefully accepting your answer soon :)

Comment: I used the "run as script" function in Oracle SQL Developer with "@C:/file.sql" and it works like a charm! Thank you :)